# I created the tenant according to the official documentation, but the creation failed;

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

I created the tenant according to the official documentation, but the creation failed;

the [doc](https://docs.cnosdb.com/zh/latest/manage/tenant.html#%E5%88%9B%E5%BB%BA%E7%A7%9F%E6%88%B7) as follow:

```
CREATE
TENANT [IF NOT EXISTS] tenant_name WITH [comment = ''/drop_after = '7d'];
```

and I create tenant as follow:

```
public ❯ CREATE
TENANT  tenant_010 WITH;
```

but the error returned, as follow:

```
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: Expected identifier, found: ;"}
```

what's the problem?